# How to give template file reference from the azure storage in Adobe.PDFServicesSDK document merge operation

Tags: azure, pdf-generation, azure-storage, adobe, adobe-pdfservices

I am trying to give file reference from the cloud storage. Below code is taking file reference from local path. I am writing azure function so need to replace below logic with azure storage. Can you please help me out?

```
// Create a new DocumentMerge Options instance
                    DocumentMergeOptions documentMergeOptions = new DocumentMergeOptions(jsonDataForMerge, OutputFormat.PDF);
    
                    // Create a new DocumentMerge Operation instance with the DocumentMerge Options instance
                    DocumentMergeOperation documentMergeOperation = DocumentMergeOperation.CreateNew(documentMergeOptions);
    
                    // Set the operation input document template from a source file.
                    //documentMergeOperation.SetInput(FileRef.CreateFromLocalFile("C:\\Work\\Study\\C# Tutorial\\Tekura.PDFSigning\\Tekura.PDFSigning.DocumentCreate\\" + @"salesOrderTemplate.docx"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking, how do you use a file as input that's external to your function, you cannot. You must provide a local file, or a stream. If you can stream *from* Azure Storage, then you could use that. Or you could download the file into temp storage and use that. But - in general - our services can NOT directly use cloud based file storage.